# How to store and Retrieve List in database Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to store the python **List** data type value into DB. Please find the below code I am using.

**Model.py**

```
 class Counter(models.Model):
    myList = models.TextField(null=True) # JSON-serialized (text) version of your list
```

**views.py**

```
import simplejson as json
def CTS_upload(request):
    -----Some logic---
    myModel = Counter()
    listIWantToStore = [0,]
    -------Some code logic-----
     i = i + 1
    count.append(i)
    listIWantToStore.append(i)
    myModel.myList = json.dumps(listIWantToStore)
```

**Problem:** here each time when I am uploading a .xls file a new **list** object is getting created. I want changes to happen in the same existing List.
Please find the below image.

[image]

problem2: When I am trying to decode I am getting the below error.
*Exception Type:   TypeError
Exception Value:   Input string must be text, not bytes*

```
def countclear(request):
    jsonDec = json.decoder.JSONDecoder()
    myPythonList = jsonDec.decode(Counter().myList)
    print(type(myPythonList))
    print(myPythonList)
    ------Remaining code---
```

Any help on this how to create OR edit existing and retrieve values would be very helpful.

Comment: This `myModel = Counter()` will create a new instance of type `Counter`. If you want to overwrite an existing DB entry, you need to load it. To do so, you need some kind of identifier, usually the primary key: `myModel = Counter.objects.get(id=...)` In you screenshot, there is a column `id`, that's the default primary key in Django's DB tables.

Comment: Thanks @C14L, after using 
def CTS_upload(request):
 myModel = Counter.objects.get(id=28)
If I'll use like this first it is checking obj 28 exist or not and each time its content is changing but I want to append it to the existing list. above I have hardcoded it but how to use it without specifying the id 28.

Comment: That depends how you get the data you use to upgrade the row. You need to remenber an identifier to tell Django what row it is that you want to update. Without a unique identifier, there is no way to know. Usually, such an identifier would come together with the data.